# how to tell warbler to not read local rakefile

Tags: jruby, warbler, rakefile

Is there a way to run `warble war` in such a way that it will not read the local Rakefile? In other words, I want to be able to have a borken Rakefile, but have it not affect warbler at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason warbler loads the `Rakefile` is to be able to run a rake `environment` task if it exists.  If you don’t want warbler to load your project `Rakefile`, set the following value in the `config/warble.rb` file in your project:

```
 Warbler.framework_detection = false
```